# how to test whether program exits or not

Tags: testing, python-2.7, exit, nosetests

I want to test the next class:

```
from random import randint

class End(object):
          def __init__(self):
             self.quips=['You dead', 'You broke everything you can','You turn you head off']

          def play(self):
                print self.quips[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)]
                exit(1)
```

I want to test it with nosetests so I could see that the class exits correctly with code 1. I tried differents variants but nosetest returns error like

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site.py", line 372, in __call__
    raise SystemExit(code)
SystemExit: 1

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 5.297s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Ofcourse I can assume that it exits but I want for test to return OK status not error. Sorry if my question may be stupid. Im very new to python and I try to test something my very first time.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the [assertRaises context manager](http://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises). Here is an example test that ensures that the play() method exits:

```
import unittest
import end

class TestEnd(unittest.TestCase):
    def testPlayExits(self):
        """Test that the play method exits."""
        ender = end.End()
        with self.assertRaises(SystemExit) as exitexception:
            ender.play()
        # Check for the requested exit code.
        self.assertEqual(exitexception.code, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the traceback, `sys.exit()`* raises an exception called `SystemExit` when you call it.  So, that's what you want to test for with nose's `assert_raises()`.  If you are writing tests with `unittest2.TestCase` that's `self.assertRaises`.

*actually you used plain built-in `exit()` but you really should use `sys.exit()` in a program.

Comment: I tried : def test_End():
    end=End().play()
    assert_raises(SystemExit(1),end) but it does not work

Comment: @user2569002 use `assert_raises(SystemExit,end)`, not `assert_raises(SystemExit(1),end)`.  It expects a callable.

Comment: I'd recommend the assertRaises context manager - I think it leads to more legible tests.